# Как в C++ отсортировать массив

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Как в С++ отсортировать массив чисел с плавающей точкой так, что бы числа были от меньшего к большему в целой части, а в случае одинаковых целых частей, от большей к меньшей в дробной. Т.Е.
При входных данных : 5,3; 6,4; 3,2; 5,1; 5,2;
Вывод: 3,2; 5,3; 5,2; 5,1; 6,4;

Comment: Написать соответствующий компаратор...

Comment: Я не понимаю немного как он работает, уже неделю сижу над этим, пытался изучить как работает компаратор. Но особо понятнее не стало, только понял для чего он вообще существует. Только начал изучать С++ к сожалению, а это нужно прям очень срочно.

Comment: Вам надо написать функцию, которая сравнивает два числа, и возвращает `true`, если они, грубо говоря, идут в требуемом порядке. Выделяйте целые части, сравнивайте. Если одинаковы — смотрите на дробные. За вас полностью писать код никто не будет...

Comment: Т.е. если числа идут в нужном порядке, возвращает true, если числа идут в неправильном порядке false? И ещё такой вопрос, допустим числа идут через несколько друг от друга, перебором сравнивать с предыдущими?

Comment: Просто функция `bool compare(double a, double b)`. Потом вся сортировка — это просто `sort(arr, arr+N, compare);`

Comment: Нет, это я как раз таки понимаю. Я про то , что компаратор работает так что возвращает true если порядок правильный, в противном случае false?

Comment: Как узнать тогда какой порядок правильный? Если числа идут просто по возрастанию, а когда встречается одинаковая целая часть, числа наоборот идут по убыванию, как только целая часть поменялась, числа вновь идут по возрастанию?

Comment: @АнатолийПлешков, если вам покажут два числа вы сможете определить какое больше (больше в том смысле о котором вы спрашивали)?

Comment: Да, конечно. Эта задача не сложна в решении руками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Утомился объяснять. Держите, сдавайте...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool comp(double a, double b)
{
    if (floor(a) < floor(b)) return true;
    else if (floor(a) > floor(b)) return false;
    else return fmod(a,1) > fmod(b,1);
}

int main()
{
    double a[] = {5.3, 6.4, 3.2, 5.1, 5.2 };

    sort(a, a+5, comp);

    for(auto x: a) cout << x << "  ";
}
```

https://ideone.com/PMYQd8

Comment: Я понимаю что вопросы глупые. Но я не хотел получить просто код. Я искал объяснения в интернете и мне было крайне непонятно. Данная задача была примером, придуманным с одногруппником. Срочность была связанна с началом изучения С++, т.е. имелось ввиду понять в ближайшие пару дней как устроена сортировка, До этого только фронтендом занимался. И очень многие моменты пока не понятны,это был один из них. Спасибо Вам большое)